# How to add relations for built-in models in Loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I've questions about working with build-in models in Loopback.
I need to extend my built-in model - User with custom relations.

```
// Extend properties
var properties = {

};

// Extend options
var options = {
    relations: {
        rooms: {
            type: "hasMany",
            model: "Room",
            foreignKey: ""
        }
    }
};

// Call method
loopback.Model.extend('User', properties, options);
```

But it isn't work in my case, after restarting server model has't new rest-method and new properties.

Maybe I do something wrong, but maybe now communite has new solution for it?

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot modify built-in models.

Instead create a MyUser model that extends User, and modify MyUser, add it relations, methods etc.

You can hide User later on if you only want to see MyUser in the API explorer.